# Laravel Http Client Request How To Include An Array Of Strings?

Tags: laravel, http, client

I want to send a Http Client Request to Bluehost Domains API. I want to include an array of domain names and an array of tlds In my request, as follows:

```
    public function multipleDomainsAvailable($domainsArray, $tldArray)
    {
        $urlSegments = "api/domains/available.json";

        $response = Http::dd()->get("https://test.httpapi.com/" . $urlSegments, [
            'auth-userid' => xxxxxxxx,
            'api-key' => env('BLUEHOST_API_KEY_DEMO'),
            'domain-name' => $domainsArray,
            'tlds' => $tldArray,
        ]);

        if(! $response->ok())
        {
            return $response->body();
        }

        return $response->json();
    }
```

`$domainsArray` is an array of strings and so is `$tldArray`. When I dump the response, I get some weird encoding between the domain-name and the value?

```
auth-userid=xxxxxxxx&api-key=myKey&domain-name%5B0%5D=smurfs&domain-name%5B1%5D=weirdness&domain-name%5B2%5D=fellow&domain-name%5B3%5D=demonize&tlds%5B0%5D=com&tlds%5B1%5D=net&tlds%5B2%5D=org&tlds%5B3%5D=info"
```

I get an error message saying the required parameter domain-name is missing?

Comment: "_I get some weird encoding_": `%5B0%5D`, `%5B1%5D` .. are `[0]`, `[1]` when decoded. Does the API allow sending an array of domain-names?

Comment: In the documentation here, it says use an array of strings?

Comment: https://cp.cn.bluehost.com/kb/answer/764

Comment: The API doesn't allow the sending of an array of domain-name,  every domain-name parameter must be included one by one?